# How to put the BarCode reader/scanner output in textarea of form developed in swing Java

Tags: java, swing, barcode

I have one form with the BarCode on it.Whenever I read it by BarCode reader,it shows me the output at the cursor position on screen instead of showing it at the textarea on the form developed in Swing Java. What should I do for this ?

Comment: can you post some code, please?

Comment: What scanner are you using? Does it work as a keyboard? Maybe it has a dedicated API.

Answer (score 0):

Two options, make the form field have focus before scanning... or capture keyboard events and direct them to the form field.

Comment: Thanks Chris,let me check this.